# Robot Framework: How to sort by

Tags: robotframework

I have a webpage with a combobox to sort a list by Price, Name,... The list is in many pages, so I need to get all elements first and after, I will sort by and check if the elements are correct. Right?

I am trying to do it and navigate for all pages and get all elements. But it is only taking the elements in first page. I am totally new in Robot framework. 
Does anyone have a suggestion how I can do it?

```
${name_list_actual}    Create List     
${cnt_pages}=    Get Element Count    //div[@class='container index-new-p']/div/nav[@class='text-center']/ul/li/*
Log To Console    ${cnt_pages}
:FOR    ${n}    IN RANGE    1    ${cnt_pages}
\    Click link    //div[@class='container index-new-p']/div/nav/ul/li[${n}]/a
\    ${cnt}=    Get Element Count     //*[@class="title"]/*
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${cnt}
    \    ${get_names}    Get Element Attribute    //table[@class='result-table']/tbody/tr[${i}]/td/div/div[2]/div/a    text     
    \    Append To List    ${name_list_actual}    ${get_names}
      ${get_names}=    Select All From List    //table[@class='result-table']/tbody/tr[${i}]/td/div/div[2]/div/a
\    Log To Console    ${name_list_actual}
\    Continue For Loop
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you explain what the programming issue is that you're facing?

Comment: You seem to be trying to nest your `FOR` loop in the code snippet you provided. This is [not supported](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops) in robotframework and needs to be extracted into its own keyword

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First and foremost, by your code sample's indent it looks like you're doing nested for loops - an outer one for the changing the pages, and an inner that'll get the text in each row. The thing is - Robot Framework doesn't support nested for loops - [see the documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops).

What happened on execution is the first loop (the pagination) ran with just two statements and finished:

```
\    Click link    //div[@class='container index-new-p']/div/nav/ul/li[${n}]/a
\    ${cnt}=    Get Element Count     //*[@class="title"]/*
```

Then all the rest were executed as part of the second.

A solution would be to have a keyword "Get All Values In The Table" that'll hold the inner loop, and call it in the current outer, which will paginate.

---

Another issue - you're using `IN RANGE`, passing 1 as start and `${cnt}` as end; if it had value of 4, you probably expect the tracking variable to get all values from 1 to 4.
Yet range works with the first argument inclusive, and up to - but not getting to - the second argument; thus it covers the range 1 to 3. To salvage that, you'd need to set the upper bound to cnt+1, e.g. `${cnt + 1}`.

---

Minor stuff:

You have a statement that's within the loop block, but not prefixed with `\`:

```
${get_names}=    Select All From List    //table[@class='result-table']/tbody/tr[${i}]/td/div/div[2]/div/a
```

I'm surprised it didn't give you a syntax error - it effectively breaks the loop, and the framework should complain the next lines are prefixed as if in a loop, but one is not started.

-

When you are changing the pages by the click, you are not making sure the UI has loaded the data for the new page. If this happens through ajax calls, you may very well be working with the previous page's data, thinking it is the new one - the selenium click returns control very fast, and the operands for getting the text are running - while the UI still waits for the new data and is displaying the previous one.

-

In RF version 3.1 [the loop syntax is different](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#simple-for-loop) - the block members are not prefixed with `\`, and it's closed with an `END` statement.
I'd suggest to migrate to it - a) the current one is going to be eventually deprecated, and b) in the new one the nesting would have been marked as syntax error (you're starting a new loop without `END`-ing the running one), instead of silently passing with unexpected behavior.